# How do I view a specific table from a SQlite3 databse using python?

Tags: python, database, pandas, sqlite, datatables

I use the below code to read a table called 'movies' from the database saved as 'ga2.db'

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('ga2.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
pd.read_sql_table('movies', con=conn)
```

But I get this error **"NotImplementedError: read_sql_table only supported for SQLAlchemy connectable."** and I can't seem to find an example for how I can inspect a database table so that I can inspect its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.read_sql_query` instead:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('ga2.db')
qry = '''SELECT * FROM movies'''
df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, con=conn)
```

Comment: If my [answer was useful](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) please mark it as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).